# Invalid authorization for DeepL API gossary creation

Tags: deepl

I am trying to create a glossary using DeepL's api.

This is DeepL's api for creating glossaries:
https://www.deepl.com/en/docs-api/managing-glossaries/

Under the documentation, I should be able to set an authorization header, and send a body of texts to be added to a glossary.

I am still using postman as I am probing my possibilities, but can't get it to work. I get met with a "Invalid or missing Authorization header" response.
I am able to use my authorization key to do normal translation, but not glossary creation. (I have pro account)

I tried:

- Sending a POST request at https://api.deepl.com/v2/glossaries
- Adding an API key under authorization, setting the key to "DeepL-Auth-Key" and the value to my API key
- Adding a auth_key query containing my authorization key
- Add a body just as the example was given

Am I missing something?
If my body was bad I'd be getting another error, but am currently clueless since there weren't many questions in regards to this.

Comment: not sure if of use but using a .NET API this is what I see:
Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://api.deepl.com/v2/glossaries', Version: 1.1, Content: DeepL.Internal.LargeFormUrlEncodedContent, Headers:
{
  User-Agent: deepl-dotnet/1.0.4
  Authorization: DeepL-Auth-Key xxxx
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
}

Comment: One idea: the HTTP request that DeepL needs should contain a header: `Authorization: DeepL-Auth-Key XXX` where `XXX` is the auth key (i.e. the header has name/key `Authorization` and value `DeepL-Auth-Key XXX`)
A header like `DeepL-Auth-Key: XXX` wouldn't work in this case.
Another thing: the `auth_key` parameter works for older API functions like text translations, but not for newer API functions like the glossaries (and admittedly this is not obvious from our documentation).